# Associate existing related record to an record when created

Tags: apex, relationships, childrecords

I am trying to associate an existing related record(sales rebate__c) to another custom object when it is created(Sales program__c)

Below is what I have so far but I am receiving an error where I am comparing the year on the parent child record.  How can I compare these 2 objects?
My error is:

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: `List<Sales_Rebate__c>`

```
trigger AddSalesRebateToSalesProgram on Sales_Program__c (After insert) {   

 List<Sales_Rebate__c> rebate = new List<Sales_Rebate__c>();

    for(Sales_Program__c sp : Trigger.new)
    {
      if(sp.Current_SBF_Year__c == rebate.Early_Buy_Rebate_Year__c )
      {
           Sales_Rebate__c addrebate = new Sales_Rebate__c();
            addrebate.Sales_Program__c = sp.id;  
                rebate.add(addrebate);
      }
    }

    insert rebate;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please take a moment to read/revisit the [help] and read [ask]. It is not very clear what you have tried so far or why it does not work.

Comment: I am truly not sure where to start on this.  I know if I can associate the correct related record to the PArent account my formulas/work flows work.  Even I figure out how to add a related record to a parent account ai am not sure how to validate that I am looking at the most latest related record. Thanks,

Comment: What's the relationship (parent/child) between the rebate and the program objects? When the user creates a new child record (whichever that is) would they choose the parent manually? or would they click a button directly on the parent to create a child related to it? or would it be associated for them automatically on save? (no way for user to see/change it)

Comment: The child(sales rebate__c) record will be created first.  Later in the month I pull records in from our ERP using Jitterbit which create the Parent accounts(Sales Program__c) .  I want to be able to marry the sales rebate__c record to every new Sales Program record that was created during the import.  And every year a new Sales Rebate__c record will be created and this new sales rebate record will need to be associated to all the new Sales program records that will be pulled in from our ERP.  Thanks M

Comment: @mark would it be easier to have have the Sales Rebate__c object as the parent and make the Sales Program__c object the child records?  So when the Sales Program records are imported they can be associated to the single Sales Rebate record? Thanks. M

Comment: What is your error? Please further [edit] your post to include the error message.

Comment: What are you expecting to be the value of `rebate.Early_Buy_Rebate_Year__c`, considering `rebate` is an empty list on your first iteration? Is that actually supposed to be a field on `Sales_Rebate__c`? In that case I think you just want to change `rebate` to `sp` in that equality comparison.

Comment: @AdrianLarson .  Ah, I see that now.  The Early_Buy_Rebate_Year__c is a field on the Sales Rebate object.  The Early_Buy_Rebate_Year__c and  Current_SBF_Year__c are text fields that will house a year value.  I was trying to ensure that the correct Rebate record is being associated to the correct Sales Program records based on year.  Every year a new Rebate record will be created and then multiple Program records will be created.